# config redirect to match specific pattern

Tags: c#, redirect, web-config

How do I adjust this automatic redirect in web.config:

```
<rule name="Redirect_to_https" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

in such way that the rule is applied for example

```
site1.internal.sw-company.com
site2.internal.sw-company.com
site3.internal.sw-company.com
```

to all 3 sites and subpages but NOT to addresses like: service1.internal.sw-company.com (services residing on the same server)

I am using C# and ASP.NET 4.5

Answer (score 0):

```
site\d+.internal.sw-company.com
```

Perhaps this pattern would work for you?